# What is the best way to carry milk to work?

Tags: storage

I live in Japan and milk is sold only in cartons here. I take milk to the fridge at work. I currently put it in a black plastic bottle with black cover but it stinks like it is off after only a few days. The milk is fine as far as I can tell. I doubt there is food safe plastic bottles here. I carry by bicycle and the bar fridge is small and at times very crowded as it shared so spillage is a great risk. What is the best solution? I use the milk  for adding coffee and cocoa- I may have one drink or many drinks- depends on how sleepy I am that day. I buy 1 litre cartons as I am poor but I couldn't drink 1 litre at work in a week even. The main milk is always fine.

Comment: Just for clarification: you are cleaning your container after each use, at minimum emptying it out and washing it  every second or third day? Or are you storing the milk longer?

Comment: The grocery store might not sell small containers of milk, but do any of the convenience stores sell single serving bottles?  (Although those might have a lid that’s torn off so you can’t re-seal it)

Comment: Please clarify the question. It seems to me that the solution is to just buy milk near work and store it in the fridge in the same container you bought it in, rather than buy milk near home, change the container, transport by bicycle and store it at work. I suspect that I misunderstood the question though.

Comment: @Joe I've never seen a single-serving bottle of milk in Japan, only single-serving cartons.

Comment: Bottles are only sold in special stores.

Comment: What's wrong with just keeping it in the carton you bought it in? (Whether you bring it from home or buy it near work.)

Comment: Temperature has a huge effect on how long milk keeps, IME. Make sure the fridge is getting cold enough and make you're putting the bottle in the coldest part of the fridge that won't freeze. Someplace convenient like the door may be the worst (warmest) place.

Comment: The milk liquid is good condition after a couple of days- bubbly and  fine smell.

Comment: Er, milk shouldn't be bubbly...

Comment: There is an old joke... *How does a cow carry her milk to work?*

Comment: I'm assuming it's ESL milk? Would switching to UHT milk be an option?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key thing is that you **empty and wash the container regularly** (ideally daily, but at least every few days). If there is a bad smell that is a sign that something is wrong; most likely some milk remained somewhere like a screw top or drops on the lid, which has gone off in some way.

**Any bottle sold for drinking water should be food safe** in terms of its material, so I would be very surprised if you cannot find anything. However, I would try to find a bottle which:

- is **easy to clean** completely, so no complicated closing mechanism or built-in drinking straw.
- will provide reasonable **insulation** while the bottle is out of the fridge, for example a thermos bottle (which uses vacuum in the walls to insulate the contents).

Anything suitable for carrying hot coffee is likely to work well for your needs, in case that's a useful way to search.

Comment: Good advice.  Also, just the process of pouring from one container to another exposes it to air for a while.  I wonder if there is something in the air where the transfer is occurring that could be contaminating it, if the bottle is being cleaned each time.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a "disposable" drinking water bottle; it could be replaced fairly frequently (and washed every time it's emptied which should be every few days at the longest).  But if that takes up too much fridge space, a tip from my parents is to use a small glass jar, with just 1 day's worth in it.  I wouldn't buy an insulated bottle, but if the commute is long use an insulated sleeve or pouch.  It can be hard to check insulated bottles are completely clean.

Comment: Also, be sure to give the screw threads for and in the cap a good clean, probably with a brush.  If the contents taste fine but it smells bad, there's a good chance that's where old milk is lingering and going off

Comment: *wash the container regularly* in a dishwasher with a heating element that gets the water up to 200f. - Don't hand wash with 125f water and wonder why....

Comment: They don't have a standard for bottle in Japan for consumers. I was considering a travel bottle but it is not dark plastic.

Comment: @Mazura does anyone still have near-boiling dishwashers? It's very rare to see over 70°C (260°F) as the hottest program these days on European models, and typical programs are 50-60°C (120-140°F), which do a very good job of getting things clean and fresh

Comment: @user2617804 why do you want dark plastic?  You sounds as if  that's a requirement but milk is usually packaged in translucent containers in most countries, even under bright lights - light doesn't do any harm

Comment: @Mazura Different materials have different appropriate cleaning temperatures, so there isn't really a blanket rule. 200f, for example, is going to melt most types of plastic.

Comment: "Any bottle sold for drinking water should be food safe" - any bottle sold for drinking water should be food safe ONCE. Reusing the plastic bottles that drinking water and sodas typically come in [carries some risk](https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/is-it-safe-to-reuse-plastic-water-bottles) of harbor harmful bacteria and (depending on the type of plastic) chemical leaching. Bottles that are sold empty, specifically for repeated use, should be more trustable.

Comment: @NotThatGuy That article's conclusion is that chemical leaching "isn’t normally a concern", and bacterial growth can be mitigated by washing thoroughly (as has been suggested).

Comment: The FDA says, "4- 501.112 gives the requirements for the temperature range of the hot water sanitizing rinse. This sets a ceiling of 194°F and lists different lower ends at 165°F and 180°F depending on machine type." https://paperthermometer.com/blogs/posts/what-does-section-4-7-of-the-fda-food-code-mean - If that melts your bottle then it's not the right bottle.

Comment: I changed to an American brand of outdoor water bottle.

Answer (score 7):

**Sterilized shelf stable milk in small cartons.**

[image: milk]

https://www.morinagamilk.co.jp/english/products/jp/

Order a bunch and bring the unopened cartons to work.  Or ask the store where you shop to start stocking it.

Comment: I thought there was a tradition of drinking milk after onsen (hot spring baths), so I’d be surprised if there wasn’t milk available in smaller sized containers.  But those might not be designed to re-seal, or flavored (fruit milk, coffee milk, etc)

Comment: Maybe not as common, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't any in the US. Isn't the one [here](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Parmalat-Whole-Milk-32-fl-oz/151857624?athbdg=L1600) from Walmart's US site one of them? It's in a carton and says "refrigerate after opening" on the side. It even says "Made in the USA".

Comment: You can get it in the UK, but it's not particularly popular. This is probably because it tastes nothing at all like milk. it is entirely its own flavour & many people, including me, think it's revolting ;))

Comment: That is going to spill in the fridge due to shaking.

Comment: In the US, Parmalat shelf-stable milk is available in most supermarkets (I'm on the East coast) and from Amazon. As @unlisted mentions above, it has a different taste than fresh milk, but it can stay on the shelf for quite a long time.

Comment: @user, no an open carton won't randomly spill in a fridge unless someone knocks it.  That might be an issue in a crowded shared fridge, especially if full

Comment: I must object to the rascally statement that "every other country has it". In fact my only experience with the stuff is [that scene from Speed 3.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBwwcU2c3u4)

Comment: @Daron - Assuming that wasn't a laugh track about how crappy it tastes, the stuff is horrible?

Comment: @user, no an open carton won't randomly spill in a fridge unless someone knocks it. That might be an issue in a crowded shared fridge, especially if full – 
Chris H
 It is a crowded shared bar fridge- just opening the door would cause some spray.

Comment: @Mazura I am told it is horrible. But I cannot say myself because it is not on the shelves where I live.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is not entirely clear, so I will answer for both possible options.

### If you are trying to keep the milk for multiple days in the fridge

It will become unsafe after 3-5 days, there is no way around that. If you switch to UHT milk, it will still be unsafe 3-5 days after opening the container, but it won't taste bad, so some people prefer to do it that way.

So the solution here would be to reduce the amount you are bringing to your work.

### If you are bringing new milk daily, but the bottle stinks

You are probably cleaning the bottle improperly, as the dbmag9's answer and some comments mentioned. Here, you have several options, ordered by my personal preference:

1. Stop using a (typical) bottle.

- As ChrisH said, you can start using a jar, just test first if it leaks when you shake it vigorously. You can specifically search for buying a "leakproof jar" if you find that all random jars you have happen to be leaky.
- Other alternatives would be Weck bottles with a wide mouth and a flat lid held by metal brackets (I don't think they come in single-day-sizes though),
- or a gasketed clip-lid container, there are baby-food-sized ones that hold 200 ml (downside: they aren't convenient for pouring).
- Or get creative and use a baby milk bottle - nowadays, you can get bottles with a sealing cap to exchange the nipple during transport.
- Many people nowadays use an insulated travel mug with a leakproof lid.

Whichever container you choose, aim for a transparent one, so you can see if it has been washed properly or if it still has a milky layer sticking to it.

2. Start washing your bottle properly. Many people try to get away with filling the bottle and sloshing it a bit. That never works, especially for fatty contents like milk. You need a spongy brush on a long thin stem, it is sold especially for bottle cleaning (don't use the bristle ones for milk, they are for stuck-on pieces as in fruit juice bottles). You have to stick the brush in and make sure you scrub intensively the whole inner surface with soapy water, and then clean the threads of both bottle and cap. Afterwards, do 3-5 rinses by half-filling it with clean water and sloshing it thoroughly.
   If you want to use a dishwasher, note that it only works with a wide-mouthed bottle (50 mm or more) and not too tall. Make sure that it stays vertically during the cycle, it is best to stick it on a spike and have other tall-ish items surrounding it.
3. As mentioned in comments, single-use bottles can also be used. My environmentalist hairs stand on end when I hear it :( but it would work. It would also be the most expensive solution.
4. If you only use tiny amounts of milk daily (e.g. to add to coffee or tea) consider buying single-serving milk or creamer instead, like the ones you get in coffee shops. In Europe, they are available in large supermarkets, and I assume that in Japan, you can at least find them online. Alternatively, there is also powdered creamer available.

Comment: Baby bottles are perfect - they seal well _and_ are designed to be not just cleaned (formula is worse than milk) but also sanitized. And usually come in different sizes.

Comment: @Stephie that's exactly why I suggested them - it is possible to find other bottles of a comparable size, but baby bottles were designed to work exceptionally well with milk. It may still not be optimal, if it becomes the grounds for mobbing ("did our baby bring his bottle to work again"), or hurts the OP's reputation at work (I believe that Japanese companies have an extremely low bar for what counts as an inexcusable eccentricity, but I don't know what's their view of food containers specifically).

Comment: Baby bottles with alternate lids to seal them aren't anything new.  My parents used them for my younger siblings 35+ years ago.  (Presumably they used them 40+ years ago as well, but I don't remember that far back.)

Comment: Using a baby bottle has the additional happy benefit of lessening the odds that a co-worker will "borrow" milk when OP isn't looking.

Comment: USDA says milk can be kept (refrigerated) for a week (7 days) after it's opened: https://ask.usda.gov/s/article/How-long-can-you-keep-dairy-products-like-yogurt-milk-and-cheese-in-the-refrigerator If the OP is having milk go off only a couple of days after being opened then something else is wrong besides it just being milk. (Source: I live in the US, we only buy groceries once a week so the milk has to last at least a week!)

Comment: **Baby bottles** - you know, those vessels made out of a plastic *specifically* for milk, +1. And you're supposed to have a bottle brush. @user3067860 Unless you're transferring it in a clean room, even if the bottle is immaculate, it induces contamination. Presumably it's the milk they transfer into another uncovered container, take it to a fridge that gets opened and loaded with new stuff 1000x a day, which is going bad. *milk can be kept (refrigerated) for a week* provided it is still in its uncontaminated original container and not unduly exposed to pathogens, especially a mouth.

Comment: @user3067860 Almost certainly that information is for dairy products _sold in the USA_. Possibly, but not necessarily for other places where other manufacturing methods are used.

Comment: "It will become unsafe after 3-5 days" what sort of milk or fridge do you have? Milk stays good for way longer (source: a bottle of milk in my fridge opened 10 days ago)